# How do I play a video in monomac?

Tags: video, monomac

I want to play video in my monomac software.

The AV foundation library is available but there is no documentation for this anywhere. I want to create a video control, so I can add it to an NSView and play videos. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use the AVVideo or AVPlayer objects but I can't get either of these to do anything.

Hope somebody out there knows the answer. If I can just get started I'm sure I can figure out play/pause/volume etc myself.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
MyPlayer=AVPlayer.FromUrl(new NSUrl("http://......"));
MyPlayerLayer=AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer(MyPlayer);
this.ContentView.Layer=MyPlayerLayer;
this.ContentView.WantsLayer=true;
```